# How to make a spring boot app with tomcat embeded be able to run at weblogic?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, weblogic12c

I am trying to run my spring boot app (made through Jhipster) on a web logic server.

It works great with its embeded tomcat, but once I remove the tomcat dependency I start to see more errors.

Currently this one:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage (default) on project myproject: Execution default of goal org.springframework.boot:spr
ing-boot-maven-plugin:1.5.9.RELEASE:repackage failed: Unable to find main class -> [Help 1]
```

This happens after I removed

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Is there any way I can package my app to make it run on weblogic? I am novice when talking about WL.

Any idea?

Comment: This should help: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#build-tool-plugins-maven-packaging

Answer (score 1):

Please read the spring docs reference

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html